# Laravel email confirmation email sent or failed, Email preview and editable

Tags: email, laravel, laravel-5

Laravel5 Currently i am facing issue unable to check the status email is sent and not even getting email failed and i am using mandrill api for sending emails

```
$mail = Mail::send('emails.pendingorder', $data , function($message) use ($domain, $order)
{
   if ($order->other_email) {
      $message->from($domain->email, $domain->website);
      $message->to($order->email, $order->name)->subject('test Email ');
      $message->bcc($order->other_email, $order->name)->subject('test Email ');

   }else{
      $message->from($domain->email, $domain->website);
      $message->to($order->email, $order->name)->subject('test Email ');
   }
});

if($mail){
   echo 'sent';
}else{
   echo 'Fail';
}
```

The second thing..
i created email templates in blade and i want to preview email in ckeditor if there any any chaning or modification require then i edit the content and send email. i havn't any idea how to to this :(

Its my first try with laravel email and i am totally stuck with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have correct configuration in config/mail.php? Remember to change **pretend** to **false**. Also, Mail::send returns void, so you will have to check status on your mandrill account.

For editing email before sending it:

- create form with ckeditor
- fill this form with your default template
- after submitting you have email body in your request, you can pass it to your email view

If you want your email to be fully editable, instead of having email view with only one variable you can use:

```
Mail::raw('This will be body of your email', function($message) {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: yes i set retend to false and email is sending find but i want to save in database email sent or not is there any way to get reponse.. Btw for editing email its sounds good let me give it a try

Comment: Have you tried sending email in any other way? It would help to determine if it is mandrill config/api issue. I do not believe you can, as mandrill does not always send email right away. Looking at companies which use mandrill, you can be quite sure, that if email address is correct, it will reach it's destination [sooner or later](http://status.mandrillapp.com)

Comment: But we have to also track for our logs who sent emais... i also used mandrill and mailgun.. i dont want every user login to mandrill to check the email history...

Comment: i have to save in Database btw can you show me little code example i have no idea how to do this

Comment: This depends what you already can do. I suggest starting [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/database). You have to create: migration (creates table in database), model (represents entry in your database). If you create them and name model `User`, after sending mail you can just add:
 
    `$user = new User();
    $user->email = ...;
    $user->save()`
 
Which will save user in your database.

Comment: sorry you miss understood i was saying i need a confirmation save in database if email sent or not like i send some notification to user on some action on against that action one email will be send to user and i want to save that email response in database like Email sent or email sent failed..

Comment: Maybe try [Ashleydw/Mail](https://github.com/ashleydw/mail)? It says that it extends Laravel's mail to return status. There is an example for mandrill.

Comment: last thing i need i have to send ckeditor html in email raw sending html as text and i am unable to find any way even i set view('emails.content')->with('content',$content); after this sending email and getting error undefined $content

Comment: sorry for disturbing my problem just solved :) Thanks buddy for your help